# AVURLAsset status stuck on AVKeyValueStatusLoading; loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler never completes

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer to stream audio. Before beginning to play from a URL, I call

```
[self.currentlyLoadingAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[@"playable", @"duration"] completionHandler:^{
    [self evaluateAssetStatusForEpisode:episode asset:self.currentlyLoadingAsset];
}];
```

Only when that completionHandler executes will I reevaluate the item to see if it's ready to play.

But for one user, the completionHandler suddenly is not firing. He cannot stream audio from the web (but can still play downloaded tracks). Logging

```
AVKeyValueStatus status = [asset statusOfValueForKey:@"playable" error:&error];
```

, I find that the status is continually AVKeyValueStatusLoading. It never updates, but AVKeyValueStatusLoading never returns an error.

I have tried putting `loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys` on the main thread, removing the `duration` key, and making `currentlyLoadingAsset` a property to ensure it's not getting released.